# Laravel 5.7 Gate::allows Non-static method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::allows() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error in Laravel 5.7 when using Gate::allows in my formRequest class.

I was using this: `use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate;` and it didn't work,

so I replaced it with this: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate` and it worked.

I really need to know why the first didn't work and what is the difference between the two. I have tried looking up stuff but I need a more direct and concise explanation. 
Any help or pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/facades

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a Laravel application, a facade is a class that provides access to
>   an object from the container. The machinery that makes this work is in
>   the Facade class. Laravel's facades, and any custom facades you
>   create, will extend the base Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade class.
>
> The Facade base class makes use of the __callStatic() magic-method to
>   defer calls from your facade to an object resolved from the container.
>   In the example below, a call is made to the Laravel cache system. By
>   glancing at this code, one might assume that the static method get is
>   being called on the Cache class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        $user = Cache::get('user:'.$id);

        return view('profile', ['user' => $user]);
    }
}
```

> Notice that near the top of the file we are "importing" the Cache
>   facade. This facade serves as a proxy to accessing the underlying
>   implementation of the Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory interface.
>   Any calls we make using the facade will be passed to the underlying
>   instance of Laravel's cache service.
>
> If we look at that Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache class, you'll see
>   that there is no static method get:

```
class Cache extends Facade {
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'cache'; } }
```

> Instead, the Cache facade extends the base Facade class and defines
>   the method getFacadeAccessor(). This method's job is to return the
>   name of a service container binding. When a user references any static
>   method on the Cache facade, Laravel resolves the cache binding from
>   the service container and runs the requested method (in this case,
>   get) against that object.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades#how-facades-work)